# Direct enum vs Enum<> .. What is the exact technical difference?

Tags: java, enums

Given the following enum:

```
public enum Letter {
    Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta;
}
```

Then both of the following compile without error:

```
Letter       letter1 = Letter.Alpha;
Enum<Letter> letter2 = Letter.Beta;
```

Calling `getClass()` or `name()` or `ordinal()` on both `letter1` and `letter2` shows the same results.

But! The following will compile:

```
switch( letter1 ) {
case Alpha:
case Beta:
}
```

While this will not:

```
switch( letter2 ) {
case Alpha:
case Beta:
}
```

So what, if any, is the exact technical difference between these two variables?

Comment: It turns out that, because of the restrictive type bound (`T extends Enum<T>`), the only class that can implement `Enum<Letter>` is `Letter` itself.  But the type system doesn't know this, so it does not conclude that the value set of `Enum<Letter>` consists only of the constants of `Letter` and nothing else.  In general, you very rarely use `Enum` directly, except as a type bound.  (Not unlike `AbstractList`; almost the only places it is used is in the `extends` clauses of its subclasses.)

Comment: @Zabuzard No it isn't. It is a base class of `Letter`, simple as that. That's why the assignment is possible, but the switch cases aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Letter` is to `Enum<Letter>` as `Integer` is to `Number`.  A subclass to a superclass.  The only difference is that `Enum<>` is a privileged superclass that's related to a certain language feature.  (See [`java.lang.Record`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html) for another such privileged superclass.)

If we have these two variables:

```
Integer n1 = 1;
Number  n2 = 2;
```

... then this works:

```
jshell> switch(n1) { case 1: System.out.println("one"); break; default: System.out.println("not one"); break;}
one
```

... but this does not:

```
jshell> switch(n2) { case 1: System.out.println("one"); break; default: System.out.println("not one"); break;}
|  Error:
|  incompatible types: java.lang.Number cannot be converted to int
|  switch(n2) { case 1: System.out.println("one"); break; default: System.out.println("not one"); break;}
|        ^--^
```

In both cases, the compiler can't prove (prior to runtime) that `Number` or `Enum<Letter>` is something it can switch on, so it won't let you do that.